# LDAP user password authentication using JNDI

Tags: java, ldap, jndi

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String INITCTX = "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory";
    String MY_HOST = "ldap://Localhost:1389";
    String MGR_DN = "cn=John,ou=Users,o=IT,dc=QuizPortal";
    String MGR_PW = "password";           

    //Identify service provider to use
    Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, INITCTX);
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, MY_HOST);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, MGR_DN);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, MGR_PW);

    try
    {
        // Create the initial directory context
        InitialDirContext initialContext = new InitialDirContext(env);

        System.out.println("Context Sucessfully Initialized");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
}
```

I would like to ask when I set the `MGR_DN = "cn=John,ou=Users,o=IT,dc=QuizPortal"` to `MGR_DN = "uid=103,ou=Users,o=IT,dc=QuizPortal"`. Basically changing from cn to uid, I would encounter an error

```
javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - Invalid Credentials]
```

I am authenticated when is specified as `cn=John` but not `uid=103`. Am I not allowed to specify by uid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to specify the DN or distinguished name. That's the name the user is bound as in the directory. You can't just select any chain of attributes. If your users are bound via the 'cn' attribute then only the 'cn' attribute is part of the DN.

Comment: Oh... THANKS! Got it... was wondering why it didnt work... THANKS

Comment: It depends on the LDAP directory.  Some allow alternate naming attributes in which case uid=103 might work.  Whereas others will not.  So it is not a reliable approach.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't know the exact DN in advance, you should do a search in the LDAP directory first. This can be done more or less like this (make sure you catch the relevant exceptions):

```
Properties env = new Properties();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ldapServerUrl);
env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "none");

SearchControls searchCtrls = new SearchControls();
searchCtrls.setReturningAttributes(new String[] {});
searchCtrls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);

String filter = "(&(cn=" + identifier + "))";

DirContext ctx = null;
ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> answer = ctx.search(
   ldapBaseDN, filter, searchCtrls);

String fullDN = null;
if (answer.hasMore()) {
    fullDN = answer.next().getNameInNamespace();

    ctx.close();
    ctx = null;

    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, fullDN);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);

    ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
    return true;
}
// Exception otherwise ...
```

Here, the search filter is `"(&(cn=" + identifier + "))"` (so, for example `(&(cn=John))`), but you could use the `uid` instead. Uniqueness of the results depends on the configuration of the LDAP server. The base DN also depends on the way it's set up (it could be `ou=Users,o=IT,dc=QuizPortal` in your example).

Comment: That will just help you get the full DN when you only have the uid or cn, for example. Typically, some LDAP servers are configured to have unique uids across a subtree. Doing the search helps you find the right user. For example, if you've organized your LDAP tree to have multiple sub-trees (`ou=Marketing` and `ou=Finances` for example), with `uid=user1,ou=Marketing,o=MyCompany` and `uid=user2,ou=Finances,o=MyCompany` and configured it to use unique uids across `o=MyCompany`, you can find the full DN of user with `uid=user1` (which you need to authenticate) using that sort of search.

Comment: Hey thanks for the sharing. Now i have a better understanding of LDAP :)
Btw, your piece of code works like a charm. THanks!

Comment: Hi Bruno,

I want to do the same thing. to get the dn from uid and to authenticate it using the password. i tried you code but it throws the error "In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection." how to tackle this??

Comment: CAUTION, be aware that this implementation might allow users to authenticate with an empty password. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12359831/java-ldap-make-it-not-ignore-blank-passwords . Depending on the LDAP server implementation, you will also need to check that the password variable is not empty.

Comment: Why do you have this `ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);` before you `return true;`

Comment: @kaushalpranav This is off the top of my head, and 8 years later, so you'll need to check, but as far as I remember, the first `new InitialDirContext(env)` makes the search and the second one (just before `return true`) does the authentication. If the authentication fails, it should throw an exception (and therefore not reach true).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a server configuration issue. [Here's a similar problem including a solution](http://forums.alfresco.com/en/viewtopic.php?t=12859). Basically you'll have to specify whether to use `uid` or `cn` for authentication in `ldap-authentication.properties`.